# Python: double randomization of str in list

Tags: python, random

I would like to receive randomized list values. In the 1st step, I want to receive a random language code and given that code in the 2nd step, I would like to receive a random value from a list based on the randomly selected language in the first step:

```
import random
lang = ["lang_fr", "lang_en"]
lang_choice = random.choice(lang)
print(lang_choice)

lang_fr = ["fr1", "fr2", "fr3"]
lang_en = ["en1", "en2", "en3"]
lang_choice_no = random.choice(lang_choice)
print(lang_choice_no)
```

Unfortunately, the output is only one character from the two words `en` or `fr`, for example, just `e`. But it does not return (randomly), f.ex. `en3`. How can I solve this?

Comment: I guess you need `lang_choice_no = random.choice(lang_en)` instead of `lang_choice_no = random.choice(lang_choice)`. The output you see is correct because `lang_choice` is just either "en" or "fr" and then when you do `random.choice(lang_choice)`, you just will get one of the characters, either from "en" which will be 'e' or 'n' or from "fr"

Comment: @roganjosh: That's what I am saying. Read my full comment again

Comment: Ok, I was completing my comment before you commented. You should slow down :D We are in parallel universes, remember?

Comment: My typing speed. I rest my case :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a dictionary with your language choices as keys and your possible second choices as values, then select from the values based on key:

```
>>> lang = ["fr", "en"]
>>> lang_choice = random.choice(lang)
>>> lang_fr = ["fr1", "fr2", "fr3"]
>>> lang_en = ["en1", "en2", "en3"]
>>> lang_dict = {'fr':lang_fr, 'en':lang_en}
>>> lang_choice_no = random.choice(lang_dict[lang_choice])
>>> print(lang_choice_no)
'en1'
```

Comment: Thank you very much :-) Values based on keys works well!

Answer (score 0):

So what you are doing here is first you are asking python to return a random choice from the list lang. Which it does. It returns a string such as `"fr"`.

Then you are later asking it to return a random choice from the variable `lang_choice`, which was a random choice (and thus now a string), so it returns a random character from the previous choice.

Can you explain what you are attempting to do at step 2? you want to select a random value from within one of the lists? or what?

```
import random
lang = ["fr", "en"]
lang_choice = random.choice(lang)

if lang_choice == "fr":
    languages = ["fr1", "fr2", "fr3"]
elif lang_choice == "en":
    languages = ["en1", "en2", "en3"]

lang_choice_no = random.choice(languages)

print(lang_choice_no)
```

Comment: Sorry, 2nd line of code of course needs to be `lang = ["lang_fr", "lang_en"]`. Thus, as you said I would like te select a random value from one of the lists, based on the randomization in the 2nd step. Thank you

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean, can you be more specific, is what I assumed your problem to be correct?

Comment: Thank you very much! :-) Of course, this works. I thought there could be a more "elegant" way

Comment: there probably is a more elegant way, storing these choices in lists was quite strange to begin with. You can start with 1 list and then just check for the string fr or en and then do a decision. It really depends on what you are trying to achieve.